# How to close newsletter popup automatically after signup - Shopify

Tags: popup, shopify, newsletter

I am not a programming expert so bear with me.
I have put up a shopify site with the template Icon-Christian. It comes with newsletter popup. The thing is that after signing up, the popup window doesn't close automatically. How can I edit the code?

```
{% if settings.popup %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  if($(window).width() > 500){
    // Fancybox Join our mailing list popup
    $(document).ready(function(){

      var check_cookie = $.cookie('mailing_list_delay_popup');
      if(check_cookie == null){
        $.cookie('mailing_list_delay_popup', 'expires_seven_days', { expires: 7 });
        //fire your fancybox here
        setTimeout(function(){
          $.fancybox({
            href: "#subscribe_popup"
          });
        }, 3000);
      }
    }); 
  };

</script>  
{% endif %}

<div style="display:none">
  <div id="subscribe_popup" class="row">
    {% if settings.email_popup_image %}
    <div class="left fifty">
      <img src="{{ 'popup-image.jpg' | asset_url }}">
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="right fifty">
      <h3>{{ 'layout.homepage.mailing_list_join' | t }}</h3>
      <p>{{ 'layout.homepage.mailing_list_text' | t }}</p>    
      <!-- BEGIN #subs-container -->
      <div id="subs-container" class="clearfix">
        <div id="mc_embed_signup">
          <form action="{{ settings.mailchimp }}" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">
            <input value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="{{ 'general.newsletter_form.newsletter_email' | t }}" required="" type="email">
            <input value="{{ 'general.newsletter_form.submit' | t }}" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" type="submit">
          </form>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <ul id="footer-icons">
        {% if settings.show_facebook %}<li><a href="{{ settings.facebook_url }}" target="_blank"><i class="icon-facebook icon-2x"></i></a></li>{% endif %}
        {% if settings.show_twitter %}<li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/{{ settings.twittername }}" target="_blank"><i class="icon-twitter icon-2x"></i></a></li>{% endif %}
        {% if settings.show_pinterest %}<li><a href="{{ settings.pinterest_url }}" target="_blank"><i class="icon-pinterest icon-2x"></i></a></li>{% endif %}
        {% if settings.show_tumblr %}<li><a href="{{ settings.tumblr_url }}" target="_blank"><i class="icon-tumblr icon-2x"></i></a></li>{% endif %}
        {% if settings.show_youtube %}<li><a href="{{ settings.youtube_url }}" target="_blank"><i class="icon-youtube icon-2x"></i></a></li>{% endif %}
        {% if settings.show_googleplus %}<li><a href="{{ settings.googleplus_url }}" target="_blank"><i class="icon-google-plus icon-2x"></i></a></li>{% endif %}
        {% if settings.show_instagram %}<li><a href="http://instagram.com/{{ settings.instagram-id }}" target="_blank"><i class="icon-instagram icon-2x"></i></a></li>{% endif %}
      </ul> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give me a test link?

Comment: thank you so much for replying... I think I managed it by redirecting it to the homepage :)